# Finding a confidence interval for difference of proportions

Tags: confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, link-function, profile-likelihood

Let two independent random variables, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ that have binomial distribution have parameters $n_1 = n_2 = 100$, $p_1$ and $p_2$, respectively, be observed to be equal to $y_1 = 50$ and $y_2 = 40$. Determine an approximate $90\%$ confidence interval for $p_1 - p_2$.

---

I'm pretty new to confidence intervals and wanted help on this problem from my book. I have tried to apply the following definition:

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be a sample on a random variable $X$, where $X$ has p.d.f. $f(x;\theta)$, where $\theta\in \Omega$. Let $0 < \alpha < 1$ be specified. Let $L = L(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ and $U = U(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ be two statistics. We say that $(L, U)$ is a $(1 - \alpha)100\%$ confidence interval for $\theta$ if $1 - \alpha = P_{\theta}(\theta \in (L, U))$.

However, I have been having trouble applying this definition directly. I can identify $\alpha = 0.1$ here, which means that I think we want $P(L < p_1 - p_2 < U) = 0.9$. Now I'm really not sure how to use this information to get the answer; I have no clue where the observed values would come into play.

Comment: Cross-post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4057729/321264.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this. I will show one modern way, using profile likelihood. First we use binomial regression, but with an *identity link function*. That is not usual, but in cases such as this, where the only regressor is a factor variable, it can work fine. Then we can profile the log likelihood function to get an approximate confidence interval. With code in R this can look like, with your data:

```r
mydat <- data.frame(n=c(100, 100),  y=c(50, 40), 
                    group=factor(1:2))

mod0 <- glm(cbind(y, n-y)  ~  group, 
            family=binomial(link="identity"),
            data=mydat)

confint(mod0, 2)
```

giving the following output

```r
Waiting for profiling to be done...
      2.5 %      97.5 % 
-0.23531653  0.03781719
```

This likelihood profile confidence interval corresponds to the likelihood ratio test. For some details and other examples see [Constructing confidence intervals based on profile likelihood](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9833/constructing-confidence-intervals-based-on-profile-likelihood),   [Profile Likelihood: why optimize all other parameters while tracing a profile for a partitcular one?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/371854/profile-likelihood-why-optimize-all-other-parameters-while-tracing-a-profile-fo),   [What is the relationship between profile likelihood and confidence intervals?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77528/what-is-the-relationship-between-profile-likelihood-and-confidence-intervals)

Some similar posts, with answers giving other methods: [P value and confidence interval for two sample test of proportions disagree](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57104/p-value-and-confidence-interval-for-two-sample-test-of-proportions-disagree),   [Comparing the distributions of proportions in two groups](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/397530/comparing-the-distributions-of-proportions-in-two-groups/397541#397541),   [Change in binomial proportion confidence interval](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58667/change-in-binomial-proportion-confidence-interval)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to use the definition that I have been provided (i.e., I don't want to use any computing software) to find the answer. How can I do this?

Comment: Then you will have to use one of the standard (asymptotic, that is, based somehow on a normal approximation) formulas. I will add to the answer, but look at some of the links in the last paragraph.

Comment: I find this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/401884/237901) of yours, which calculates the profile likelihood confidence interval "by hand", more informative.