# How to correct Chi-square's p-value when working with very unbalanced contingency tables?

Tags: r, p-value, chi-squared-test, unbalanced-classes, profile-likelihood

I'm studying the association between a rare disease and smoking. Because the disease is rare, my contingency table is highly unbalanced with way more Non-Diseased than Diseased individuals, independently of their smoker status.

```
            NonDiseased | Diseased
___________ ____________ __________
Smoker     |    4312    |    16
___________ ____________ __________
Non-Smoker |   21329    |    20
___________ ____________ __________
```

Is there a way to correct the p-value of a chi-square test done on this table to reflect the fact that there are very few Diseased individuals?

Comment: What issue do you see with the usual p-value?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other excellent answers:

To get more precise inference, you can model via logistic regression. That can always be done with a $2\times 2$ contingency table, and then use likelihood methods. I will show profile likelihood used to get more precise confidence intervals for the log-odds ratio, a confidence interval is also more informative than a p-value only. With R code:

```r
Smoker   <-  rep(c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No"),  
                 c(4312, 21329,  16,  20))
Diseased <-  rep(c("No",  "No",  "Yes",  "Yes"), 
                 c(4312, 21329,  16,  20))

mydata <- data.frame(Smoker   =as.factor(Smoker),
                     Diseased =as.factor(Diseased))
rm(Smoker, Diseased)

 mod0 <- glm(Diseased  ~  Smoker, data=mydata, 
             family=binomial)
summary(mod0)

confint(mod0, 2)
 
Call:
glm(formula = Diseased ~ Smoker, family = binomial, 
          data = mydata)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.0861  -0.0433  -0.0433  -0.0433   3.7344  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -6.9721     0.2237 -31.170  < 2e-16 ***
SmokerYes     1.3755     0.3358   4.096  4.2e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 544.98  on 25676  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 530.05  on 25675  degrees of freedom
AIC: 534.05

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 9

    Waiting for profiling to be done ...
    2.5 %    97.5 % 
0.7032746 2.0316117
```

Exponentiating the confidence limits then gives a confidence interval for the odds ratio:

```r
exp(c(0.7032746,  2.0316117 ))
[1] 2.020358 7.626368
```

which is a direct measure of effect size.  Note that this confidence interval is based on likelihood profiling, which usually is more precise than the Wald confidence intervals, which we can get by

```r
confint.default(mod0, 2)
              2.5 %   97.5 %
SmokerYes 0.7173564 2.033688
```

which in this case is not very different, probably because the sample size is so large.

If you instead want a more direct measure, like the difference in proportions, use the (similar) methods in
[Finding a confidence interval for difference of proportions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/513390/finding-a-confidence-interval-for-difference-of-proportions)

There is also higher-order likelihood inference, in R with packages `hoa`, `cond`.  We can try this to see if it makes much of a difference, but the conclusion is that, not. Again, probably because of the large sample size.  But below some results:

```r
library(cond)

mod0.cond <- cond( mod0,  offset=SmokerYes)

 summary(mod0.cond)

 Formula:  Diseased ~ Smoker
 Family:  binomial
 Offset:  SmokerYes

          Estimate   Std. Error 
uncond.       1.376       0.3358
cond.         1.375       0.3359

Confidence intervals
--------------------
 level = 95 %
                                         lower two-sided upper
Wald pivot                              0.7174           2.034
Wald pivot (cond. MLE)                  0.7172           2.034
Likelihood root                         0.7033           2.032
Modified likelihood root                0.7071           2.032
Modified likelihood root (cont. corr.)  0.6500           2.085

Diagnostics:
----------- 
      INF        NP 
0.0139565 0.0003413 

 Approximation based on 20 points
```

The modified likelihood root interval is supposed to be the most accurate, but the different intervals given here are very similar.

Comment: Doesn't `glm` give Wald-based inference, not likelihood ratio?

Comment: @Dave: yes, but confint is based on profile likelihood, so is approximate likelihood-based. I will add details when back at home

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line is that the proportions of diseased subjects among smokers and non-smokers are 0.0037 and  0.0011, respectively, and they are highly significantly different.

Because counts 16 and 20 are relatively small some statisticians might use the **Yates continuity correction,** which is conservative (making the chi-sq statistic smaller, hence the P-value larger). With or without this 'correction' your P-value is very small.

Computations in R below:

```
TBL
      [,1] [,2]
smok  4312   16
nons 21329   20


chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with Yates' continuity correction

data:  TBL
X-squared = 17.658, df = 1, p-value = 2.644e-05

chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 19.58, df = 1, p-value = 9.649e-06
```

The expected counts (all larger than 5) in this chi-squared test are sufficiently large for a good approximation of the null distribution
to $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = 1).$

```
chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)$exp
          [,1]      [,2]
smok  4321.932  6.067999
nons 21319.068 29.932001
```

Answer (score 1):

Imbalance alone is not an issue for a chi-squared test, although a small absolute number of counts can be - applying a chi-squared test to a 100:1 imbalanced dataset will work fine if you have a million samples, but not if you have a hundred. With sufficient sample size, a chi squared test could be appropriately applied to data with any level of imbalance. As long as there are enough counts in the rare group, it doesn't really matter what proportion of the whole they are.